# Сортировка чисел и вывод их на экран

Tags: java

1. Введи с клавиатуры 20 чисел, сохрани их в список и рассортируй по трём другим спискам: число делится на 3 (`x % 3 == 0`), делится на 2 (`x % 2 == 0`) и все остальные. Числа, которые делятся на 3 и на 2 одновременно, например, 6, попадают в оба списка.
2. Метод `printList` должен выводить на экран все элементы списка с новой строки.
3. Используя метод `printList`, выведи эти три списка на экран. Сначала тот, который для `x % 3`, потом тот, который для `x % 2`, потом последний.

Я сделал 1 и 2 пункты. Как сделать 3 пункт?

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list32 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
        while(true) {
            String s = rd.readLine();
            if (s.isEmpty())
                break;
            int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (x % 3 == 0) {
                list3.add(x);
                printList(list3);
            } else if (x % 2 == 0) {
                list2.add(x);
                printList(list2);
            } else if ((x % 3 == 0) && (x % 2 == 0)) {
                list32.add(x);
                printList(list32);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printList(List<Integer> list)
    {
        //напишите тут ваш код
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый пункт вы сделали неправильно:
1. У вас можно ввести больше или меньше 20 чисел.
2. Число в список `list2` добавляет не всегда когда нужно, а в `list32` вообще ничего не попадает, да и название у него странное - в задании намёка на такой нет.

По самому коду:
1. Конструкции `while (true)` стоит избегать.
2. `InputStreamReader` и `BufferedReader` нужно закрывать после использования.

В итоге получается как-то так:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> others = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            String line = rd.readLine();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if (number % 3 == 0)
            {
                list3.add(number);
            }
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                list2.add(number);
            }
            if (number % 3 != 0 && number % 2 != 0)
            {
                others.add(number);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { }
    printList(list3);
    printList(list2);
    printList(others);
}

public static void printList(List<Integer> list)
{
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: а чем плохо `while(true)`?

Comment: @pavel если действительно нужен бесконечный цикл, то это не плохо. Но не припомню на практике таких ситуаций. Как правило, `while` всё же имеет условие для выхода. И если это условие расположено где-то внутри тела `while`, то это усложняет чтение кода. А ещё в первую секунду, только увидев `while (true)`, можно справедливо подумать, что цикл действительно бесконечный.

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили! @Regent

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось вот так:

```
    package Generics;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> othr = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String s = reader.readLine();
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
        for (Integer x : list) {
            if (x % 3 == 0) {
                odd.add(x);

            }
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                even.add(x);
            }
            if(x % 3 != 0 && x % 2 != 0) {
                othr.add(x);
            }
        }
        printList(odd);
        printList(even);
        printList(othr);

    }

    public static void printList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

Просмотри код если вопросы будут с радостью отвечу

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Понял вас, уже исправил